# Scrolling Navigation Bar Help Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I was wondering how to create a navigation bar 
like the one at the top of the screen that moves when "flicked" or scrolled.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`HorizontalScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html), wrapped around a `LinearLayout` of Buttons or `ImageButtons`.